# Azure automation: runbook is failing

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am using a simple workflow to stop a VM. It is executing fine and showing everything fine. But When I am cross checking my VM is not getting stopped. Is there anything which I am missing here ?

```
workflow StopVM
    {
      inlineScript
      {
         Stop-AzureVM -Name "VM123" -ServiceName "Service123"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have missed to add credential to link to azure. Without making link you can't run azure-cmdlts. However you can do the same thing using certificate also.

Here is some stuff-

[Stop-AzureVM does not shutdown my Azure-VM (Runbook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027625/stop-azurevm-does-not-shutdown-my-azure-vm-runbook/29099189#29099189][1])